# Switch off the lamp in imported VRML

Tags: python, scripting, import

In my VRML file, I have lights switched off. But when I render it in blender (by using the import tool), the lights are switched on.

I looked at the code:

```
def importLamp_PointLight(node, ancestry):
    ....
    # is_on = node.getFieldAsBool('on', True, ancestry) # TODO
    ....
```

As I can see in the code, lamp's `is_on` has not been implemented.
But I need this to work. How can I contribute to the code and make this work?

I see the this is implemented in `bpy.data.lamps`, but it uses C code `_bpy imports types`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try uncommenting the is_on line and add something like

```
bpylamp.hide = not is_on
bpylamp.hide_render = not is_on
```

Another option could be

```
if is_on:
    bpylamp.energy = intensity
else:
    bpylamp.energy = 0
```

The X3D/VRML2 import script was written by Campbell and Bart so you might want to contact them and ask what they planned to do with the lights and whether they want some help. It's possible they left it like that because there is no on/off light switch in blender (maybe adding one is a TODO somewhere).

Comment: I think you are correct. The camera button is hide_render one. I used your ```bpylamp.hide_render = not is_on``` solution, however not exactly. Because hide_render is an attribute of ```bpy.data.object```and not of ```bpylamp```.

Comment: `hide` will hide the lamp in the viewport - this also applies to preview rendering in the viewport, `hide_render` will only hide it while rendering - as in final image rendering. There isn't a switch that turns off both at the same time.